# Fetching data from Core Data on application launch

Tags: swift, core-data

I need to check for items in my `Core Data` when the app launches. this is what I wrote so far, but I don't think this is the best practice (although it is seems to be working) is there any other way? better way to acheive what I need?

```
func getMealsFromCoreData() -> [Meal]{
    var retrivedMeals = [Meal]()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Meal")

    do {

        let result = try managedContext?.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject]{
            retrivedMeals.append(data as! Meal)
        }

    }catch{
        print("Failed to fetch.")
    }

    return retrivedMeals
}

func uploadMeals(){
    var mealsToUpload = [Meal]()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "mealQueue", qos: .background)
    dispatchQueue.async {
        mealsToUpload = self.getMealsFromCoreData()
        for meal in mealsToUpload {
            print(meal)
        }
    }
}
```

Upload meal should upload to meals to the screen after fetching everything (maybe not the best function name).
This is what I wrote in the AppDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
DataManager.manager.uploadReports()
```

I get in getMealsFromCoreData a purple warnning that says appDelegate should run on the main queue.
I'm really confused with this CoreData + Moving CoreData fetch from the main thread to the background.

Would really appericiate your help guys.
Am I doing something wrong? What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the warning says what you are doing wrong.

The best practice depends on the use case. But it is certainly not fetching all data on application start. Fetch the data when you need it, as much data as you need (to display).
Maybe have a NSFetchedResultsController to maintain the data for your view if that is an option for you.

Comment: I did try to put it in the homepage of my app, the problem is that it gets executed eveytime the user goes back to the homepage screen. It can be solved with a flag but I wanted to see if there is another,more correct approach to this.

Comment: Did you try to setup a NSFetchedResultsController in viewDidLoad of your homepage screen (that i suppose to be there all the time) - and just have the UI update when changes are being made?

Comment: Didn’t know I can only execute when changes made. Didn’t catch that when I looked at the docs. I will try to look again. Thanks!